# graphics and network controllers not working after last update for Ubuntu14.04

Tags: drivers, kernel, updates

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I installed the recommended updates yesterday. When I booted again the PC, the OS did not detect the Ethernet controller. Moreover, the graphics performance was very bad: The second screen was not detected and the one that was being used had not the size properly adjusted.

I tried booting with another kernel through the GRUB and then it worked good, as before the update. With kernel 4.4.0-70 it shows all the problems I mentioned; and with the kernel 4.4.0-67 it works good.

I would like to solve the problem and being able to work with the latest recommended kernel. If not, I would like to know how can I automatically boot with the older one without specifying it every time.

Comment: Wait, so did you upgrade to 16.04?

Comment: Nope. I just installed automatic updates, mostly containing Linux headers. I don't know exactly which ones I installed. If anyone knows how to get that, I will edit the OP with them